# Angular Subscription not Triggering twice when data is the same

Tags: angular, rxjs

Have tried using both subject and behaviorsubject from Rxjs, and i cant seem to find a way to make a way for a subscription to fire if the data is the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9S3b.png)

Comment: please put your code in your _question_ not in an image.

Comment: Subject does not hold old data, behavior subject does not check data on „next“. So both will fire twice if you send same data.